# I can not configure e-mail Jenkins Extension

Tags: email, jenkins, build, continuous-delivery

Shortly:

I'm using "E-mail Notification" on my Jenkins, its setuped on my local machine. I can not configure emial notifications.

My configuration:

1. SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
2. Default user e-mail suffix:
3. Use SMTP Authentication: Checked
4. User Name: My Gmail mail (i turn off only safe app)
5. Password: ****
6. Use SSL: Checked
7. SMTP Port: 465

```
Failed to send out e-mail

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)

    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)

Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)

Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)

    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)

Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)

    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)

    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:613)

    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:535)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:280)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:676)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)

    at hudson.plugins.locale.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:42)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)

    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)

    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)

    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)

    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)

    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)

    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think everythink is ok, email should be send.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https:///systemInfo >> javax.net.ssl.trustStore.
This is the truststore where the certificate should be added.

You can open the keystore with keytool or if you prefer a GUI take a look at Keystore Explorer

The default password of the truststore is changeit.